# Visual Studio not accessing instance of a class asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, instance

I use this function `List<LineData> list = LineData.getData();` in my aspx.cs page, to reference my class to get my data. Only problem is my query no longer contains the element I am receiving the error on. I receive a invalid object name error. I tried breakpoint and it never reaches any breakpoint I set even on page load (I put the breakpoint on the `List<LineData> list = LineData.getData();`) This is also very first thing on page load. We changed the database and I changed the connection string in the config file and the table name in my query. I do not understand why this is happening. I am not sure what code to post in the instance so what ever you want to see let me know.

**It says my old connectionstring is what is an invalid object name.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'BeforeWorkOrder'.]
   DataClassLibrary.LineData.getData() +980
   Line1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\K\Dropbox\K's Stuff\CoolerManagement\Line1.aspx.cs:16
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Here is the problem spot on my aspx.cs page

```
List<LineData> list = LineData.getData();
```

Here is my DataClass

```
public static List<LineData> getData()
{
    List<LineData> list = new List<LineData>();

    StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
    sqlString.Append("SELECT * ");
    sqlString.Append("FROM WorkOrder ");
    sqlString.Append("WHERE LineCompleted =  'false' ");

    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlConnection dbConn = DBHelper.getConnection();

    try
    {
        reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), null);
        if (reader != null)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                **Data ld = new **Data();
                ld.OrderID = (int)reader["OrderID"];
                ld.PNumber = reader["PNumber"].ToString();
                ld.ItemCode = reader["CaseNum6"].ToString();
                ld.BrandCode = reader["CaseNum9"].ToString();
                ld.CasesRemaining = (int)reader["CasesRemaining"];
                ld.Group = (Group)reader["Group"];
                list.Add(ld);
            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
            dbConn.Dispose();
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("No records returned");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dbConn != null)
        {
            try { dbConn.Close(); dbConn.Dispose(); }
            catch { }
        }
        if (reader != null)
        {
            try { reader.Close(); reader.Dispose(); }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure your class isn't actually `**Data` - was this the result of search and replace?

Comment: It would help if you'd fix your post so it's actually valid code then.

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: @TTat problem spot on my aspx.cs part.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos I meant in the getData() method.

Comment: @TTat it doesn't, stops at the top. I added a edit with the **

Comment: you need to post the stack trace so we can figure out the exact error and what line it's occurring on

Comment: @AndrewCounts give me just a sec.

Comment: Btw, you don't need that `StringBuilder`. Actually it just obfuscates the code and is even less efficient than a simple (verbatim) string literal. Apart from that, i hope there's nothing static in `DBHelper`. You should use the `using`-statement for the connection instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you and I edited my post with trace.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Are you using Linq2Sql?

Comment: @AndrewCounts trace is up.

Comment: appears that the problem is not in the `GetData()` Method but in the constructor for `LineData`

Comment: @TTat wait maybe I set a connectionstring in web.config

Comment: @AndrewCounts make a new one?

Comment: we should take this to a chat channel and not use comments for ongoing troubleshooting

Comment: @AndrewCounts How do I open a chat usually it offers.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45408/discussion-of-issues-with-kapt-khaos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a mismatch in your database table and your data model.

How to: Update an .edmx File when the Database Changes (Entity Data Model Tools):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716697(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It should have been generated for you.  How are you mapping your data model to your database tables?

Comment: I'm not I literally in my web.config file set the connection then call it when I need it.

Comment: Do you have a query anywhere else?  Based on the error message, it looks like it's trying to get data from the column 'BeforeWorkOrder' that doesn't exist in your database.  I would do a search on the whole solution for 'BeforeWorkOrder'